# Set x axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2` for the x axis I have year values from 2011 until 2019. I expected to see this values in the plot

However I receive comma separated values like this
[image]

How is it possible to change the values to show the years?

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Year` column to factor?

Comment: @RonakShah you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: `scale_x_date`. If your date is in date format add this line of code to your ggplot code:

```
library(scales)

  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y"))
```